# Accessing singleton EJB from another webapp in TomEE

Tags: java, singleton, openejb, apache-tomee

I have 2 webapps deployed on Apache TomEE+. In the first webapp I have created a singleton EJB class declared like this:

```java
@Singleton
@Remote
@Startup
@Lock(READ)
public class SolverRegistryBean implements SolverRegistry
{
    // ...
```

From openejb.log I can see, that the singleton is available:

```
2011-12-05 20:43:22,696 - INFO  - Jndi(name=SolverRegistryBeanRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=SolverRegistryBean)
2011-12-05 20:43:22,696 - INFO  - Jndi(name=global/localhost/SolverCore-1.0/SolverRegistryBean!grid.solver.SolverRegistry) --> Ejb(deployment-id=SolverRegistryBean)
2011-12-05 20:43:22,696 - INFO  - Jndi(name=global/localhost/SolverCore-1.0/SolverRegistryBean) --> Ejb(deployment-id=SolverRegistryBean)
2011-12-05 20:43:22,750 - INFO  - Started Ejb(deployment-id=SolverRegistryBean, ejb-name=SolverRegistryBean, container=My Singleton Container)
```

From my other app I want to access that singleton bean, so I do:

```java
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
    "org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory");
p.put("java.naming.provider.url", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/openejb/ejb");
try {
    ctx = new InitialContext(p);
    SolverRegistry reg = (SolverRegistry)ctx.lookup(
        "openejb:global/global/localhost/SolverCore-1.0/SolverRegistryBean");
```

but then I get ClassCastException

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy94 cannot be cast to grid.solver.SolverRegistry
```

I checked that this $Proxy94 class implements interfaces: *grid.solver.SolverRegistry*, *org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.IntraVmProxy* and *org.apache.openejb.BeanContext$Removable*.

Why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved my problem by changing the lookup line to:

```java
SolverRegistry reg = (SolverRegistry)ctx.lookup("SolverRegistryBeanRemote");
```

Still don't know what is *openejb:global/global/localhost/SolverCore-1.0/SolverRegistryBean* for.